# Values from 2 variables are being swapped in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have modified a stored procedure and added an extra parameter to be added to a table. The problem is the value for the added parameter is being swapped with an original parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spWeb_BulkGenerateWRsDevices]
(
    @WorkRequestDeviceId nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @TechnicianId int = NULL,
@RequiredBy  datetime = NULL,
@Priority   int = NULL,
@WRTypeId int,
@WorkRequestSummary nvarchar(255) = NULL,
@AuthorOfRequest   int,
@Contact nvarchar(40) = NULL,
@PhoneNo  nvarchar(20) = NULL,
@StatusId int,
@Created  datetime = NULL,
@CustomerId int
)
AS
/* Update the WR record */
BEGIN
DECLARE @COUNT INT
SET @COUNT =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WorkRequest WHERE WorkRequestDeviceId IN(SELECT stringval FROM     dbo.CSV(@WorkRequestDeviceId)))

IF @COUNT >0

BEGIN
DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (WorkRequestId int,WorkRequestDeviceId int)

INSERT INTO WorkRequest 
(AllocatedTo,RequiredBy,Priority,WRTypeId,WorkRequestSummary,AuthorOfRequest,
    Contact,PhoneNo,StatusId,DateOfRequest,WorkRequestDeviceId,CustomerId)

OUTPUT Inserted.WorkRequestId,Inserted.WorkRequestDeviceId INTO @InsertedRows

     SELECT @TechnicianId ,@RequiredBy,@Priority,@WRTypeId,@WorkRequestSummary,@AuthorOfRequest,@Contact
        ,@PhoneNo,@StatusId,@Created,@CustomerId,* from dbo.fnSplit(@WorkRequestDeviceId, ',')

END

IF @COUNT = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO WorkRequest 
(WorkRequestDeviceId)
SELECT * from dbo.fnSplit(@WorkRequestDeviceId, ',')

UPDATE WorkRequest 
SET 
AllocatedTo =@TechnicianId ,
RequiredBy = @RequiredBy,
Priority = @Priority,
WRTypeId = @WRTypeId,
WorkRequestSummary =@WorkRequestSummary,
AuthorOfRequest= @AuthorOfRequest,
Contact = @Contact,
PhoneNo = @PhoneNo,
StatusId = @StatusId,
DateOfRequest = @Created,
CustomerId = @CustomerId
WHERE WorkRequestDeviceId IN(SELECT stringval FROM dbo.CSV(@WorkRequestDeviceId))

END
```

I have added the CustomerId parameter. When I call the procedure and say set WorkRequestDeviceId = 312 and CustomerId = 148 the table WorkRequest has a new record but with WorkRequestDeviceId = 148 and CustomerId = 312. I am new to stored procedure so sorry for my ignorance, any ideas?
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert is transposing the variables in the insert statement and the select.

Change your insert to read:

```
INSERT INTO WorkRequest 
(AllocatedTo,RequiredBy,Priority,WRTypeId,WorkRequestSummary,AuthorOfRequest,
    Contact,PhoneNo,StatusId,DateOfRequest,CustomerId,WorkRequestDeviceId)
```

And all should be fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy response, I actually figured it out myself as soon as I posted.